# How to change JSON text of MySql database to JSON datatype of postgres sql

Tags: postgresql

How to change JSON text of MySql database to JSON datatype of postgres sql.I am storing JSON data in database table of  Mysql and want to convert it into JSON datatype of postgres sql

**Mysql create table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employee` (
  `id` bigint(40) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employee_id` bigint(40) NOT NULL,
  `employee_info` text NOT NULL,
  )
```

In employee_info I am storing {"employee_name":"abc","address":"1","emloyee_weight":"30","age":"100","phone":"9845236775"} 
in MySql database which is a JSON .

and wanted to convert it into JSON datatype of postgressql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question shouldn't left unanswered :-)

It's pretty simple:

**Postgresql CREATE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
  id bigserial primary key,
  employee_id bigint NOT NULL,
  employee_info json NOT NULL
);
```

**And then you can some magic like:**

```
select * from employee where employee_info->>'address' like '%Kr%';
```

or

```
select * from employee where CAST(employee_info->>'emloyee_weight' AS integer)>30;
```

Heed on postgres version, it should be 9.3 or greater

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/edb87/1